# php & postgres : query failed

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Through a php form, I try to retrieve a primary key value from postgres so that I can then update a table.
the little bit of html:

```
<p>
Saisissez le numéro sga de l''opération
</p>
numéro sga :<input type="text" name="num_sga"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="rechercher">
```

and the end of php where I define the query then execute it and store the result in `pg_fetch_result`. This is the execution of the request that doesn't pass because when I replace `$_POST[num_sga]` with a real value, it works. I don't know something...

```
//la définition de la requete de maj à compléter
$sqlGid = "select gid from activite.emprise where numope = 
'$_POST[num_sga]'" ;
//execution de la requete
$requete_gid = pg_query($sqlGid) ;
//recuperation du gid depuis le résultat donné par la requête ci-dessus.
$gid = pg_fetch_result($requete_gid, 0, 0) ;

$maj = "update public.metadonnees set (date_rapport, date_libe_terrain, 
généalogie) =
    ('$_POST[date_rapport_maj]', '$_POST[date_libe_terr_maj]', '$_POST[genealogie_maj]')
    where gid = $gid " ;
```

Comment: Used prepared statements.

Comment: under the assumption that you  actually have a `<form>` element surrounding your html code, did you check, that your input actually reaches your code? (`print_r($_POST);` for example). then you should use prepared statements otherwise you're vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: pg_fetch_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on PostgreSQL result index 4 is always what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains some php code, which can't be understood by sql. So what your query actually does is looking for the string `$_POST[num_sga]` in the `numope` field...

You need to first prepare a statement with a placeholder:

```
// Prepare a query for execution
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'select gid from activite.emprise where numope = $1');
```

And then execute the statement, passing actual value to it:

```
// Execute the prepared query.  
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array($_POST[num_sga]));
```

Note that this way is better in many ways than simply doing:

```
$sql = 'select gid from activite.emprise where numope = ' . $_POST[num_sga];
pg_query($sql);
// ...
```

Why ? Because:

- it is more secure: the value will be escaped and thus avoid basic sql injection
- it is more efficient: the prepared statement can be reused, so you only need to prepare it once. You can then do the `pg_execute` as many time as you want
- it is more readable
- etc.

Look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) and google for more information on *prepared statements*.

Comment: Iti s weird because I often use this method (bad habit never trust input user). And it has always worked...until now...